# Is is safe for an application to hit a get request from codebase to any user specified url

Tags: python-3.x, http, security, https, python-requests

Wanted to confirm that would it be safe for an application to have a get request made to any user specified url using requests module in python.
Are there any security concerns regarding that, and any best practices to follow.
We have a 10 seconds timeout applied on the get call.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is not secure. There is so called [Server-side Request Forgery (SSRF)](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Server_Side_Request_Forgery) attack.

So at least your server may be at risk of IP address, User-Agent (default header added by Python Requests library) disclosure. If something in your infrastructure is vulnerable, then this will bring the attacker closer to success.

Ensure that you handle response carefully, with strong validation. It might be a good idea to make a request from a separate IP address and/or obfuscate User-Agent header.

I would say that the severity of your security measures should be corresponding with how sensitive the data you are storing is.

Check the [Server-Side Request Forgery Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Server_Side_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#server-side-request-forgery-prevention-cheat-sheet) for more details.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot @zok for this information, however we are only using the url we get back from the response:
like this:
`response.url` 
we are not storing the actual response anywhere.

We have also used a specifc hardcoded value for the User-Agent

Would these steps ensure security?

Comment: If hiding IP is not a big deal in your case (like if the same IP already exposed for incoming requests), then alright.
If `response.url` will be visible to your users, then ensure that there is nothing accessible to your server (in local network around it), that can respond with redirect to some sensitive address (seems unlikely).

Comment: Note that It may be acceptable for now, but it may expose a vulnerability after a some time, when you forget about it and your backend will evolve. You should keep it in mind.